# Linked in share and hashbang url

Tags: javascript, seo, linkedin-api, hashbang

I have a question about linkedin and sharing url with hashbang (angular app).
It seems like if the hashbang is right after first slash (www.example.com/#!/someString) the LinkedIn bot will issue request for ***www.example.com/***. 
But if the shared url is like ***www.example.com/someString/#!/otherString*** linkedin bot issue request for ***www.example.com/someString/?_escaped_fragment=/otherString***.

Do you have some working solution for sharing hashbang urls? I found one stackoverflow question from 2013, but the solution was that linkedin doesn't support escaped_fragment which is not true anymore.

Thank you

Comment: This might come from a <meta name="fragment" content="!" /> on your home/root. Which means : request for an empty _escaped_fragment_. Is it ?

Comment: If I added the <meta name="fragment" content="!" /> the sharing stopped working. LinkedIn does not load anything. Is there someone from LinkedIn team able to help? Can you please tell me, what is wrong (the site I am talking about is _www.studiow.cz_. It is really sad, that on other social networks my sharing works fine, except LinkedIn.