# Problem while sharing a link with a '#' character in the LinkedIn iOS app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

If you share a link with a # in it like this one:

https://werkenbijbaetsen.nl/#216/vacature

It is shared ok on the *LinkedIn* website, its clickable and resolves fine. Also it works on the *Android app*.

However; if you open a posting like that on the *iOS (iphone) linkedin App*, it will link to a wrong page, resulting in a 404/not found on the end of the line.

This indicates a bug in the iOS app (something with url-encoding the # sign perhaps?);

Has anyone found a solution or workaround to this? Because it seems that a 302 redirect setup doesn't work properly, because then it doesn't load and users get: "Cannot display preview. You can post as is, or try another link. "

Comment: This has been a problem since 2012.  [Linked in share and hashbang url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797489/linked-in-share-and-hashbang-url)  Hashbangs, of course, indicate an anchor link in the document, and are rarely used in actual URLs.  I guess LinkedIn just didn't want to implement it?